# How to make 3 columns mobile friendly?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, mobile

I was trying to figure it out on my own, but didn't work well for me. 
I am using bootstrap and trying to make proper version for mobile users. 
Now it looks horrible on mobile devices. 
I think problem is with div classes i was trying to change them, but didn't help me that much.

Here is my code:

```
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4 content">
            <ul class="featuresBody">
                <li><i class="icofont icofont-simple-right"></i>Unlimited Domains & Subdomains</li>
                <li><i class="icofont icofont-simple-right"></i>Ulimited Email Addresses</li>
                <li><i class="icofont icofont-simple-right"></i>Unlimited Databases (MySQL)</li>
                <li><i class="icofont icofont-simple-right"></i>Unlimited Bandwidth</li>
                <li><i class="icofont icofont-simple-right"></i>SSH, sFTP/FTP acess</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 content">
            <ul class="featuresBody">
                <li><i class="icofont icofont-simple-right"></i>PHP 5/7, Perl 5, Python, Zend, phpMyAdmin</li>
                <li><i class="icofont icofont-simple-right"></i>One Click CMS Install</li>
                <li><i class="icofont icofont-simple-right"></i>Cron Job Manager</li>
                <li><i class="icofont icofont-simple-right"></i>SSL Certificate</li>
                <li><i class="icofont icofont-simple-right"></i>POP3, IMAP, SMTP For E-Mail</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 content">
            <ul class="featuresBody">
                <li><i class="icofont icofont-simple-right"></i>Daily Backups</li>
                <li><i class="icofont icofont-simple-right"></i>Detailed Logs & Statistics</li>
                <li><i class="icofont icofont-simple-right"></i>Protection From Viruses</li>
                <li><i class="icofont icofont-simple-right"></i>Advanced DDoS Protection</li>
                <li><i class="icofont icofont-simple-right"></i>24/7 Support</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks! 
P.S How can i easily test pages on mobile devices?

Comment: To quickly preview for mobile devices and if you're on Google Chrome hit `F12` and click the icon in the upper left hand corner that looks like two overlapping squares (mobile devices).

Comment: On Firefox, press `Ctrl+Shift+M` to preview for mobile devices

Comment: Just checked and the shortcut on Chrome is the same as Firefox, `Ctrl + Shift + M` when developer tools have focus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using Bootstrap, the col-xs class means that the column, and whatever it has inside it, will be squished as much as necessary to fit the contents on a mobile phone.  When you have 3 columns side by side on your desktop or lap top monitor, that makes sense, because each of the 3 columns is big enough for you to read it. 
If this is the case with your situation (which I think it is), consider changing these `col-xs` to `col-md` or even `col-lg`.  This will cause the columns not to be squished to fit the mobile screen, but instead, they will stack on top of each other so that you see the left-most column first, then scroll down, you see the one in the middle, and then further below, you see the right column.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4 content">
```

columns do not work well on vertical mobile devices. You should favor rows instead.

Answer (score 0):

You're using Bootstrap's extra small (`xs`) columns size. `xs` will always create columns no matter how small the viewport. Try using `sm`, `md`, `lg` instead, i.e. `col-sm-4`.

See [Bootstrap Grid Options](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options).

You can also provide multiple column classes to the same element for even more control. For example 50% width columns on small mobiles and 33.333% width columns on larger devices, i.e. `<div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">`.

Answer (score 0):

Two things i would like to add, you might wanna replace col-xs-4 with col-sm-4
that way they are not cramped in for a mobile screen view. Secondly your i tag for list items(little green arrow) Make it position absolute , that way when the word wrap occurs it doesnt look odd.

```
.featuresBody > li i.icofont-simple-right {
  left: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
}
.featuresBody > li {
  position: relative;
}
```